# $\langle v,v\rangle$ of a vector is $0$ only for the $0$ vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$$
V = (1,i,0)
$$

It seems that the norm of $V$ is $0$ but $V$ is not the zero vector.

Am I missing something?

$$\|V\| = \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle} = \sqrt{1^2 + i^2} = \sqrt{0} = 0.$$

Isntt the definition for $\langle v,v\rangle$ is that it equals zero only for the zero vector?

Comment: for complex vector spaces, take the conjugate of one of the arguments of the dot product

Comment: Ok got it, thanks, didnt see the $||$, stupid mistake, if the managers want, they can delete my question.

Comment: @Alon The absolute value falls out of what I said in my answer, it's not really a fundamental part of the definition.

Comment: @Alon:  I think it's a good question

Comment: If you have spaces with non-degenerate (but not necessarily positive-definite) inner product, talking about norms is tricky and you can have this situation. For $$\langle x,y\rangle_L = x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_3y_3$$in $\Bbb R^3$, we have $\langle (0,1,1),(0,1,1)\rangle_L = 0$. This sort of product is used in relativity.

Answer (score 1):

For complex inner products, the norm is defined as $\| v \|^2=\langle v,v \rangle$, but the inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is defined as $\langle u,v \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k \overline{v}_k$, so that for example $\| (1,i) \|^2=2$.

Comment: Now i see, thank you, that is more familiar,

Comment: The norm is still defined as $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}$. The conjugation occurs in the formula for the inner product so that it is positive definite.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Thanks let me fix that, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

For real vectors, $\langle u, v \rangle = \sum u_i v_i = u^{\top}v$ but for complex numbers it is $\sum \overline{u_i}v_i = u^{\dagger}v$ (conjugate-transpose).

Comment: This is the "physicist's inner product space axioms", which has linearity in the second argument and conjugate linearity in the first argument. The "mathematician's inner product space axioms" go the other way. It's not really consequential which one you use but you do need to be consistent.